# Confused about partitioning in Ubuntu 16.01 32 bit

Tags: partitioning, reinstall

I'm currently planning to reinstall Ubuntu 16.10 in my old HP Desktop. I have 320 GB HDD and 2 GB RAM. I'm a little confused with how much hard drive space to allocate for each partition.

Is it okay if I allocate just root partition and swap ?

Or should I allocate all other typical Ubuntu directories such as usr , home ,  var , boot etc  in seperate partitions ??

Answer (score 0):

A typical setup should contain 3 partitions:

1) The root partition for which about 20-30GB should be more than enough.
2) A swap partition which should be equal to the RAM size in case you need to be able to hibernate to disk, or less if you don't need hibernation.
3) The home directory which would eventually contain all the other space of your hard disk.

That way you would be able to reinstall the main OS (in the root partition) without affecting your personal files and setting (which would reside in home partition).

Comment: Yeah . I actually thought that those partitions i mentioned in my question should be seperate.  Now I'm going to allocate 500 mb for bootloader ,  40 gb for root , and 10 gb for home.   You think it's okay?

Comment: 40GB is more than okay :) However 10GB only for home? You have a 320GB. What about the rest 270GB?

Comment: I don't know what you mean bootloader. You mean the boot partition? If yes, then you could have a separate boot as well but I don't see a reason to do so. However if you decide to have it separate I would say 1GB is more reasonable choice as you may need to have 2-3 kernel images.

Comment: Ok.  I just assumed 500 mb is enough. Its okay too if boot partition is 1 gb.

Comment: I also have Windows and another 150 GB partition for putting music, video and other stuffs. I think I can share that partition with Ubuntu .

Comment: I usually won't use System partitions for putting stuffs other than system files and all . That's what I was doing with Windows. I think to do the same with Ubuntu too. What you say ?

Comment: Yes. That would work too.

Comment: Ok. Which version of Ubuntu are you using ? Using any  Windows also?

Comment: 16.04. I'm not using windows (obviously) :)

Comment: Oh . Ok. I'm actually new to this OS and having a hard time dealing with this  . There are problems with graphics.

Answer (score 0):

> Or **should** I allocate all other typical Ubuntu directories such as usr , home , var , boot etc in separate partitions?

Well you obviously don't have to. Unless you want to.

> Is it okay if I allocate just root partition and swap?

It is perfectly okay.

A better approche would be:

- 2-4 GB swap. (at least 2 GB, inasmuch as you have 2 GB RAM)
- ~100 GB for root `/` for the system.
- ~200 GB for home directory `/home/` for data storage.

This way even if the system partition is corrupted. You can still have you data intact in the other partition.

Comment: Yeah . I actually thought that those partitions i mentioned in my question should be seperate.  Now I'm going to allocate 500 mb for bootloader ,  40 gb for root , and 10 gb for home.  I have allocated totally 50 gb for Ubuntu. I will usually put personal files in another drive that I share with Windows.  So I think 10 gb home is enough. What you think ?

Comment: And what do you intend to do with the 260 GB remaining space?

Comment: I also have Windows and another 150 GB space for putting stuffs like music, video etc..

Comment: Yes, but still, I would use all the remaining space for the home directory.

Comment: Yeah .. I'm started learning Ubuntu. Getting out of Windows.

Comment: Cool! welcome brother :D

Comment: Thanks man !! But you know , its very hard for a Windows user to shift into Linux . Totally different OS. Even software installations are complicated. But I got to study it. I heard it's the most powerful OS. So need to study. Also I'm willing to study about Android, so Linux will help.

Comment: Don't worry about that. You will find your way pretty quickly. The only reason for which I still use Windows sometime is for gaming or collaborating with Windows people. Other then that it's like you said one of the best (Maybe not the best but, hey! it's better then windows! and free!...). So go ahead and embrace it. Wish you good luck. ;)

Comment: Yeah.  See you soon in another post man!!. There is a still lot to ask the community. Right now GRUB has been overwritten or removed by Windows. Now I'm behind it.  I think with installation disc I can fix it.